# Does cfhttp cache responses

Tags: caching, coldfusion

We have a Windows 2008 R2 IIS7 web server running Coldfusion 9.0.2. I have a CF file that does a cfhttp call. A change was made to the file being called and the result was a 404 error. The change was reverted back but the cfhttp call still gets the 404 error. If I copy the exact cfhttp URL and paste it into my browser I get the page without the 404. Reruning the CFtemplate with the cfhttp call gets a 404.

This leads me to believe cfhttp has a cache somewhere but I am unable to find it. Does cfhttp use a cache somewhere, if so where would it be? Or might it be an IIS7 cache? Once I find it I'm assuming I can just remove the cached file if it exists.

Thanks in advance.
Joe

Answer (score 1):

No, `cfhttp` itself should not cache responses.  My guess is that you are browsing to the URL from your workstation and not the ColdFusion server itself.  Try browsing to the URL from the ColdFusion server and see if you get the same 404.  Then start checking security settings that the server has versus your workstation.  Most likely a proxy server or some such.

**Update**

It looks like from the comments that you are still having an issue, even from the ColdFusion server. Have you tried stopping and restarting the ColdFusion service to "clear" anything it may have cached? Note that you may need to clear the server's DNS cache as well (`ipconfig /flushdns` on Windows servers).

If that still does not solve it for you then my next recommendation would be to monitor the network traffic from a working connection and compare that to the network traffic from your ColdFusion server connection.  That should pinpoint where the difference is and can even show where caching may be taking place for a particular request. There are several free software packages out there - [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com), [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/), etc.

Comment: Thanks for your response Miguel-F however I think it is CF/IIS7 web server caching related. On the web server is the file http://example.com/abc/runit.cfm. In runit.cfm is <cfhttp url="http://example.com/xyz/cold+beer" ... I get 404 error (response from the cfhttp call) when I run http://example.com/abc/runit.cfm from any browser type on any system, including the server. When I hit http://example.com/xyz/cold+beer from any browser type on any system I get the page displayed correctly. It is this behavior that makes me think it is some kind of CF/IIS7 caching thing going on.

Comment: "example.com/xyz/cold+beer" isn't a valid URL.  Prefix it with a valid protocol like "http://" or "https://".  (Modern browsers are removing this from the address bar.)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out James. The URLs all contain http://, this editor, or perhaps Chrome, removed the http:// part when I committed my response. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Have you tried changing the user agent?  I block web requests from known bot & scraper agents.  This method will use the calling user's browser's user agent instead of the default "ColdFusion" value. <cfhttp useragent="#CGI.Http_User_Agent#">

Comment: Good suggestion! I just tried using the user agent as you suggested and I still get the 404 error.

Comment: Another possibility... ColdFusion DNS caches "forever".  If the website you are accessing has recently changed IPs, ColdFusion won't be able to access it until you restart the service.  (I encountered this numerous times when I wrote a CFC for OpenWeatherMap.org.)  You can change this behavior, but then ColdFusion will check every time instead of honoring TTL.  (This is an issue with all JVM servers.)

Comment: The IP has not changed recently.

Comment: What I did to get around the issue was to change the <cfhttp> URL to something else. Runit.cfm is simply a health check script which is run to see if anything is down or not responding so I changed it to hit a differnet page on the website. This did not resolve the issue nor answer the question, if I revert back to the original <cfhttp> url it will error. I will check the original URL after the next CF restart to see if that cleared the error and will report back.

Comment: A restart of the Coldfusion instance did not remove the 404 / cached file.